# Messages from my phone show up on my macbook air

Tags: macos, icloud, messages

My Macbook air keeps getting my phone messages but since the computer is a school computer it doesn't allow me to go into iMessage.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you able to open the Messages app on the MacBook? If you are able, remove or sign out from the account from `Messages > Preferences > Accounts` and you will stop receiving phone messages to your laptop.

Comment: no the message app will only bounce and not open at all

Comment: Try George Garside's answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107120/60561

Comment: nope. still doesnt work

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might need to get from your school how they have restricted the computer. While you are gathering that information, you might ask them if they can assist with this as well. If you can document that - we love it when you can answer your own questions on the site.

Answer (score 1):

it is something you put in since you had that machine -- this is keying it to your account (without even the need for the application).

**open system preferences/INTERNET ACCOUNTS, look through each you have set up and delete what you can -- or what is related to your messages account**

this is the central directory for accounts like messages (could also be controlled or synced through icloud).